# Zend simplexml_load_file() path not working in Apache in Ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu, zend-config-xml

I am trying to load an xml file from a helper method inside scripts folder with

$styleData = new Zend_Config_Xml($this->view->baseUrl().'/styles/style1/style.xml');

And i am getting error
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/my_blog/public/styles/style1/style.xml"' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Config/Xml.php:98

Now if i do
$styleData = new Zend_Config_Xml('localhost/'.$this->view->baseUrl().'/styles/style1/style.xml');
Then everything works fine
Could you please help

Comment: My .htaccess file is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

```
$styleData = new Zend_Config_Xml($this->view->baseUrl("/styles/style1/style.xml"));
```

I usually use it to add styles , javascript files 
another example

```
  $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/reset.css"))
                ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/text.css"))
                ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/960.css"))
                ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl("css/demo.css"));
        echo $this->headLink();
```

hope that help you